# Warning preg_match() Delimiter nust not be alphanumeric or backslash - Cant fix

Tags: php, preg-match

I keep getting this error, the error is in reference to this section of code, can someone tell me what I am missing:

```
if(!preg_match("class",$parameters)) $parameters .=" class='ibox'";

$field = '<input type="' . tep_output_string($type) . '" name="' . tep_output_string($name) . '"';
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

```
!preg_match("/class/", $parameters)
```

It would be much more efficient to use [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) in this case.

```
strpos($parameters, "class") === false
```

Comment: Thanks for this, what would I use for this line: 'echo $domain . preg_replace( $search, $replace, $string);' as it is experiencing the same error.

Comment: `$search` variable probably doesn't have delimiters like `/` surrounding it either

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if( strpos($param, "class") === false ) {
    // do 
 }
```